# how to apply comet using php mysql at server side?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, comet

long polling need to block response serverside till you find answer to query
how to delay response using php mysql till i find the desired row needed
say i've a chat and i'm waiting for new mesages so how to delay response from query till anew message is inserted to database ?

Comment: See: [Simple PHP long polling chat script, too simple?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623290/simple-php-long-polling-chat-script-too-simple) [`sleep()`](http://php.net/sleep) Is what you are looking for.

Comment: PHP won't be a good option for long poll but still if you want to try it you can use sleep or usleep. You can look into http://www.phpfreechat.net/ for some inspiration on how they do it.